# How to develop a formula that shows x=0 from positive and negative

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

In the formula
$\sin(x)/x $  when the limit is approaching $0$.
I have seen videos on how to prove this, but I don't know how to make an excel formula for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Taylor expansion
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\cdots$$
$$\frac{ \sin(x)}x=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\frac{x^6}{5040}+\cdots$$